# Around Dialog everything becomes black

Tags: android, dialog

I have an Activity that is opened when the user clicks on it. Also, sometimes (in this case when the game is not started yet) there is another Activity opened. This Activity is in the form of a dialog. When this dialog pops up, everything around the dialog is black (I want it (dark) transparent). Here is the code how I start the activities:

```
private void initializeButtonStart(){
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartGame);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, GameOverviewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            if (!bussen.isGameStarted()) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(StartActivity.this, PlayerSettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the way how I make a dialog of the Activity:

```
private void setDialogWidth(){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * DIALOG_WIDTH);

    getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

I use this methods at several Activities to become a Dialog lookalike. Another Dialogs just turn (dark) transparent outside, but with this way everything becomes black around the dialog. This is the case only in Android 6, versions before I had no problems.

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

[i cant add comment so...]

in android studio you can select colors that have low opacity.if you don't have android studio so go to layout `xml` file and set background color to black and then set opacity to 0.7 or 0.6(a float between 0 and 1.0)